# On the proof of Goldstein's theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Currently reading through a functional analysis text, namely over the weak topology ($w$-topology) and weak* topology ($w^*$-topology). In the text, the author gives the following theorem:

> **Theorem**(*Goldstein*): Let $X$ be a Banach space embedded naturally into the space $X^{**}$. The closure in the $w^*$-topology of the unit ball $B(X)\subseteq X^{**}$ equals $B(X^{**})$.

What I don't understand is the begging of the proof the author gives:

> *Proof*. Let $K$ be a closure of $B(X)$ in the $w^*$-topology of $X^{**}$. Then $K$ is convex since it is the closure of a convex set. By Alaoglu's theorem$^{[1]}$, $B(X^{**})$ is closed in the $w^*$-topology and hence $K$ is a subset of $B(X^{**})$.

Namely, I don't see why by "$K$ is a subset of $B(X^{**})$".

---

$^{[1]}$**Theorem** (*Alaoglu*): For a real Banach space $X$, the unit ball $B(X^*)=\{f\in X^*:\|f\|\leq1\}$ is a compact set in the $w^*$-topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural embedding $X\to X^{**}$ is an isometric mapping. Hence, $B(X)$, seen as a subset in $X^{**}$ is contained in $B(X^{**})$. Hence,
$$
K = \overline{B(X)}\subset\overline{B(X^{**})} = B(X^{**}),
$$
where the closure is taken with respect to the weak$^*$-topology of $X^{**}$.